# converting a PIL Image to a numpy array, result looks garbled/sheared

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a Python function that takes an RGB image, looks at each pixel's RGB values (0-255) and simply finds the mean (average) of the three values. I wrote the following function:

```
def avgcolors(img_matrix):
    M, N, D = img_matrix.shape
    new_img = np.zeros((M, N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            pixel_mean = int(np.round(np.mean(img_matrix[i][j])))
            new_img[i][j] = pixel_mean
    return(new_img)
```

To me the problem seems very straight forward. Run through the image matrix indexing pixels with i, j. Find the mean of the three values in each pixel and write that to a new image matrix. However, something strange happens when I run the following:

```
pic = Image.open("red.jpg")
img = np.array(pic.getdata()).reshape(pic.size[0], pic.size[1], 3)
grayscale = avgcolors(img)
plt.imshow(grayscale, cmap='gray')
```

The "red.jpg" image and the output are shown below:
[image]

I would have thought that when the script reaches the red pixels it would average out the values 255, 0, 0 to get a grayish pixel with a value of 85. And elsewhere, it would just be black. Instead, I am not getting that and I get strange diagonal artifacts. What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Comment: usually with stuff like this, the best way to debug is to start with a really small image, then step through the code line-by-line with a debugger and make sure everything at every point makes sense. Inspect the contents of the arrays at each step and see if there's anything unexpected.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the `dtype` of your array. This line `new_img = np.zeros((M, N))` should be `new_img = np.zeros((M, N), np.uint8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `img = np.array(pic)` because PIL and numpy understand each other like that.

The `.getdata()` call should not be used. It is less efficient.

The `.reshape` *did* garble the data, but doesn't *necessarily*.

The issue you're having there is that you *mixed up width and height*.

- [`PIL.Image.size`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.size) is a `(width, height)` tuple.
- Numpy requires the *shape* to be `(height, width, channels)`.

If you use the shape `(pic.size[1], pic.size[0], 3)`, your original code would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. The problem was in converting the image to a numpy array. It seems the command

```
img = np.array(pic.getdata()).reshape(pic.size[0], pic.size[1], 3)
```

Rearranges the array in a strange way. I've simply changed this line of code for:

```
img = np.array(pic)
```

Comment: Indeed, no need to reshape, that is just going to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding correctly... if you are trying to compute the mean of an 3-dimensional array on a specific axis, you can use `np.array.mean(axis=2)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 10, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
print(image.shape) # (10,10,3)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

mean_rgb = image.mean(axis=2)
print(mean_rgb.shape) # (10,10)
plt.imshow(mean_rgb,cmap="Greys")
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The idea is correct! Part of the exercise is to avoid using numpy as much as possible and do it "manually" (with for loops)

Comment: You might use colormap 'gray' instead of 'Greys',  Pixels are white as the mean_rgb lower and dark as the mean_rgb  higher (look at the bottom left one).

Comment: this answer also doesn't address the issue OP has of converting from PIL image to numpy array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75189425/revisions

Comment: OP's issue wasn't the averaging (OP's code did that already) but the distorted output image. I adjusted the title to match OP's intent. do you need to discuss this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of this using lists.

```
image = np.array([
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*4,[[255,0,0]]*2,[[0,0,0]]*4]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10]),
    np.concatenate([[[0,0,0]]*10])
])

image = image.tolist()

def mean_image_explicit(image):

    rows = []
    
    for i in range(len(image)):
        cols = []
        for j in range(len(image[0])):
            v = sum(image[i][j]) / len(image[i][j])
            cols.append(v)
        rows.append(cols)
            
    return rows

def mean_image(image):

    rows = [[sum(image[i][j]) / len(image[i][j]) for j in range(len(image[0]))] for i in range(len(image))]

    return rows


avg = mean_image(image)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(avg,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how you build `image` from a bunch of concatenate calls, that's quite convoluted... can you express that using `np.zeros` and some slice assignment?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of this answer is.

Comment: I would guess the point is to entirely ignore the use a PIL Image, and its failed conversion to numpy array. that's one way of solving the question.